# MySQL запрос из 2ух таблиц, с подсчетом данных из 2ой таблицы

Tags: count, запрос, mysql, sql

День добрый, есть 2 таблицы в `MySQL`.

```
Table1:  
id, login

Table2:  
id, user_id
```

Необходимо из 1ой таблицы вытащить все данные, а из второй где `id == user_id` но при этом необходимо посчитать сколько таких записей во 2ой таблице (`id == user_id`)

Итог должен быть что-то вроде такого:

```
Result:  
id, login, countWithTable2  
1, Quiss, 24
```

Просто мой `dbForge mysql studio` сломался, после переустановки ОС на Win8. А я как таково `SQL` знал только за счет него =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.id, login, count(t2.id)
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.user_id
group by t1.id, login
```